# Override templates for one view page or block

Tags: views, 8, theming

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to override the base templates for one view.
I created a page with a view called **'Promotions'**.
I need to override the `views-view-field.html.twig`, `views-view-fields.html.twig`, and `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` for just the one view/page.

I read about putting it into your custom theme's template folder in it's own folder that mimics the page name.
In my case, following the example it was `views-view-fields--promotions--page`.

The overrides work but they work for all the views (pages and blocks) that I created.
Can you narrow it down to just one view/page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The pattern will be something like `views-view-promotions--display_name.html.twig`

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x

Also, I recommend you activate Twig debugging (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) to see actual suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try. I have twig debugging on but it doesn't give me suggestions when I am down to the unformatted, fields, and field.html.twig levels

Comment: Those finer grained templates may have been eliminated by your wider scale template, dependent on what did. Remove it temporarily to see if the base gives you the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To override templates for one view page or block, i guess you should add another suggestions like **views-view-fields--VIEW_NAME--DISPLAY_NAME**, to do so you should implement  [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x).
here is an example for `views_view_fields` hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_theme_suggestions_views_view_fields_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $view_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id');
  $display_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('display_id');
  $suggestions[] = 'views_view_fields__' . $view_id . '__' .  $display_id;
}
```

Now if you have a view called **Promotions** and a display called **page** you will get the following suggestion:

```
views-view-fields--promotions--page
```

you can do the same to `views_view_unformatted` hook.